# cdktf grafana alerts python sample required

Tags: python, grafana, alerts, terraform-cdk

I am looking for "working"/"syntactically correct" (python) samples for provisioning unified alerts to grafana.

A have a pure terraform config file, provided by grafana, however, the python syntax complicates it further.

Comment: Have you tried using `cdktf convert` on the terraform config? See https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/cli-reference/commands#convert

Answer (score 0):

I have not the time to post my code yet, however the only problem is defining the `model` of `RuleGroupRuleData`.

You may want to copy the model of a GUI-defined alert from here:

```
/api/ruler/grafana/api/v1/rules
```

Just copy it  using a heredoc-python string:

```
grafana_RuleGroupRuleData = [RuleGroupRuleData(            
ref_id = "A",
query_type = "",
relative_time_range = dict(from_ = 600, to = 0),  
datasource_uid = grafana_dataSource.uid, 
model = """{
"alias": "$col",
"datasource": {
    "type": "influxdb",
    "uid": "datasource_influxdb"
},
"groupBy": [ ...
"""
```